# Why does celery add thousands of queues to rabbitmq that seem to persist long after the tasks completel?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I am using celery with a rabbitmq backend. It is producing thousands of queues with 0 or 1 items in them in rabbitmq like this:

```
$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues
Listing queues ...
c2e9b4beefc7468ea7c9005009a57e1d        1
1162a89dd72840b19fbe9151c63a4eaa        0
07638a97896744a190f8131c3ba063de        0
b34f8d6d7402408c92c77ff93cdd7cf8        1
f388839917ff4afa9338ef81c28aad75        0
8b898d0c7c7e4be4aa8007b38ccc00ea        1
3fb4be51aaaa4ac097af535301084b01        1
```

This seems to be inefficient, but further I have observed that these queues persist long after processing is finished.

I have found the task that appears to be doing this:

```
@celery.task(ignore_result=True)
def write_pages(page_generator):  
    g = group(render_page.s(page) for page in page_generator)
    res = g.apply_async()

    for rendered_page in res:
        print rendered_page # TODO: print to file
```

It seems that because these tasks are being called in a group, they are being thrown into the queue but never being released. However, I am clearly consuming the results (as I can view them being printed when I iterate through `res`. So, I do not understand why those tasks are persisting in the queue.

Additionally, I am wondering if the large number queues that are being created is some indication that I am doing something wrong.

Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Celery with the AMQP backend will store task tombstones (results) in an AMQP queue named with the task ID that produced the result.  These queues will persist even after the results are drained.

A couple recommendations:

- Apply ignore_result=True to every task you can.  Don't depend on results from other tasks.
- Switch to a different backend (perhaps Redis -- it's more efficient anyway): http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. I just observed that I can actually call this twice and get results both times:
for page_str in res.join():
        print page_str

Comment: I was under the impression that rabbitmq will only persist results for a single usage. Is redis considered better for passing hundreds of thousands of very small tasks? What about memcached as a backend?

Comment: You wouldn't be passing tasks via the storage backend, just storing the results.  The task producing/consuming would still occur via an AMQP queue.  Redis performs much better as the storage backend.

Comment: Can anyone weigh in on whether using the RPC backend over AMPQ results in a ton of random queues being generated as well?

Answer (score 4):

Use `CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES` (or on 4.1 `CELERY_RESULT_EXPIRES`) to have a periodic cleanup task remove old data from rabbitmq.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-result_expires

Comment: The docs seems to imply that it defaults to being on and removes any results older than one day provided celery-beat is running.