# Getting rabbitmq weird queues

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

Listing the queues for the virtualhost gives very strange results:

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues -p rabbitmqvhost | head
Listing queues ...
0842e72ea3c84379b93d2efc21e4d245        1
aec06fbdc10545e8891c4cc2c8c71939        1
f6763cdbee9d47659bc4b662b6f8e90a        1
1776868c0cbb47ee8c08ebf421d624c7        1
5cabd24bb55348e18a8c9cdb5794e17c        1
9248e8c5502a4f608f6f4766fc91b0df        1
32d8c6ba0e7644eba7c6d6c3915db55f        1
aa6e8ddac7dc496d99107e539aee150b        1
09616cffdb1b4f25a1a3548532b0589f        1
```

There are a lot of these queues: around 20-30k. The amount is constantly growing.

Any advice why this happens?

Comment: Do you have a RPC type service running by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

AMQP backend creates a queue for each task

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636534/why-does-celery-add-thousands-of-queues-to-rabbitmq-that-seem-to-persist-long-af