# remove result queue from rabbitmq using celery

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, tornado

I'm running tornado-celery and using the rabbitmq as broker and I'm running the same issue, already posted on SO [question:14636534](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636534/why-does-celery-add-thousands-of-queues-to-rabbitmq-that-seem-to-persist-long-af) but the accepted answer didn't fits my needs.

What I want is to find a way to delete the result queue after the task is done (I need the results).
I have the `auto_delete` and the `x-expires` is set to a reasonable short time, but what happens is that the queue is never deleted until the subscribed client is removed (actually the application shutdown).

I think that I'm closed to the solution and what i'm looking for is a way to tell celery, after receiving the result to "unsubscribe" from that queue. Am I in the right way? If so how can I do?

Comment: Did you manage to figure out a good solution using rabbitmq?

Comment: I haven't found a solution using celery. I've solved implemeting it with pika.